# import list to copy select files from large folder to a new folder in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move 34k images from a large dir that has 500k images. I only need the ones on the csv I created. the code I wrote call the item but doesn't move them. I wrote the code below to test on my desktop before touching production images (10 images but only want 5 to move). I am new to scripting, appologies for any mistakes I made. Thank you for any help that can be provided. I have learned a lot on this site.

```
Get-Content -path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test1.csv"  | ForEach-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images" -Recurse $_ -Destination "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test"  }
```

this is the error I get:

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content -path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test1.csv"  | ForEach-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images" -Recurse $_ -Destination "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test"  }

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'FullName                                                           '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--------                                                           '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-087.png  '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-097.png  '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-106lf.png'.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-118.png  '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-159.png  '.
At line:1 char:80

- ... ch-Object  {Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

here is what the csv looks like:

### FullName

C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-087.png
C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-097.png
C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-106lf.png
C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-118.png
C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\10-159.png

Comment: Where are these 5 images? `Import-Csv` should be used here instead. You're currently trying to copy the folder "*images*",  to the directory of "*test*". Can you give us an example of what's in your csv file? Does it have a column name? `copy-item` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I updated the post to show the error as text and listed the csv contents

Answer (score 0):

Edited to show before & after folder contents.

Assuming your CSV file looks like this:

```
Source       
------       
apple-ABC.doc
apple-ABC.pdf
```

Then this short script will do the work.

```
$MoveList = Import-Csv -path "G:\Test\FilesToMove.csv"
For ($Cntr = 0; $Cntr -lt $MoveList.Count; $Cntr++) {
   $MIArgs = 
     @{Path        = "G:\Test\$($MoveList[$($Cntr)].Source)"
       Destination = "G:\Test\Music"}
  Move-Item @MIArgs
}
```

Note if your CSV has the paths you just need to delete the test path [G:\Test] from the Path argument. Of course you'll provide appropriate paths for all items in my example.

Folders before running code:

[image: Source Folder before running code]
[image: Destination Folder before running code]

Folders after running code:

[image: Source Folder after running code]
[image: Destination Folder after running code]

HTH

Comment: that didnt work.... it moved all 10 images rather than the 5 in the csv

Comment: '$MoveList = Import-Csv -path C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test1.csv
For ($Cntr = 0; $Cntr -lt $MoveList.Count; $Cntr++) {
   $MIArgs = 
     @{Path        = "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images$($MoveList[$($Cntr)].Source)"
       Destination = 'C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\test'}
  Move-Item @MIArgs
}'

Comment: @waemisegger you edited out the \ between images and $($MoveList.... in the -Path.
Note this is tested code so I know it works.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. unfortunately with that minor change it still moves all 10 images in the folder vs just 5

Comment: '$MoveList = Import-Csv -path "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\tes1.csv"
For ($Cntr = 0; $Cntr -lt $MoveList.Count; $Cntr++) {
   $MIArgs = 
     @{Path        = "C:\Users\waemisegger\Desktop\SSL reports - Copy\images\$($MoveList[$($Cntr)].Source)"
       Destination = "C:\users\waemisegger\desktop\test"}
  Move-Item @MIArgs
}'

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the state of the source and destination folders before and after code execution. The only thing I can think of as to why your code doesn't work is due to the - in your folder name, but I doubt that is the problem. Also did you check to see if the column title in your CSV is Source and not some other title? If so you'll have to change the code accordingly, e.g. .Source

Comment: i have modified to reflect .Fullname instead of .source. still just copies the whole folder. I even edited the csv to show only the image name rather than the full name

Comment: Sorry but I'm out of ideas. I'm sure someone else with a different view will chime in to solve this.

Comment: you still taught me a lot. I thank you for your time and efforts.